# Efficiently set row in SciPy sparse.lil_matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have sparse vectors with dimensionalities of around 200.000. I also have a matrix with the same amount of columns, and the same amount of rows as the number of vectors. I want to set all of these in an incremental fashion to the matrix, that is, the first vector should get set to the first row, and so on.

Currently, the matrix and vectors are of type scipy.sparse.lil_matrix. The vectors get set to a specific row of the matrix using the following function:

```
In [7]: us.get_utterance_representation('here is a sentence')
Out[7]:
<1x188796 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 22489 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

def set_row_vector(self, row, rowvector):
    self.matrix[row] = rowvector[0]

for row, utterance in enumerate(utterances):
    uvector = self.get_utterance_representation(utterance)
    self.utterancematrix.add_row_vector(row, uvector)
```

Where uvector is a lil_matrix of dimensionality 1x~200.000.

Creating the matrix in this way turns out to be highly inefficient, where one single text string (utterance), takes up to 5 seconds. Looking at the profiling, I have come to the conclusion that it is the setting of the vector as a row in the matrix that is the main problem.

```
     55     def set_row_vector(self, row, rowvector):
         2564609 function calls (2564606 primitive calls) in 5.046 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    22489    1.397    0.000    1.397    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.where}
    22489    0.783    0.000    2.188    0.000 csr.py:281(_get_single_element)
    44978    0.365    0.000    0.916    0.000 stride_tricks.py:35(broadcast_arrays)
    44978    0.258    0.000    0.413    0.000 stride_tricks.py:22(as_strided)
   202490    0.244    0.000    0.244    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
    22489    0.199    0.000    2.221    0.000 lil.py:280(__setitem__)
    44978    0.174    0.000    0.399    0.000 sputils.py:171(_unpack_index)
   584777    0.171    0.000    0.171    0.000 {isinstance}
    44988    0.170    0.000    0.230    0.000 sputils.py:115(isintlike)
    67467    0.166    0.000    0.278    0.000 sputils.py:196(_check_boolean)
    22489    0.154    0.000    0.647    0.000 sputils.py:215(_index_to_arrays)
        1    0.129    0.129    5.035    5.035 dsm_classes.py:55(set_row_vector)
    22489    0.120    0.000    0.171    0.000 lil.py:247(_insertat2)
    67467    0.102    0.000    0.102    0.000 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```

My question is, is there a better way to accomplish the creation of the matrix from the utterances?

(Thank you)

Answer (score 7):

First, I think your `uvector` is actually in CSR format, not LIL. This is probably for the best, however:

```
In [30]: import scipy.sparse as ss

In [31]: row = ss.rand(1,5000,0.1,'csr')

In [32]: matrix = ss.lil_matrix((30,5000))

In [33]: %timeit matrix[0] = row
10 loops, best of 3: 65.6 ms per loop

In [34]: row_lil = row.tolil()

In [35]: %timeit matrix[0] = row_lil
10 loops, best of 3: 93.4 ms per loop
```

Next, you can avoid some cost by dropping the `[0]` subscript on your `rowvector`:

```
In [38]: %timeit matrix[0] = row[0]
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop

In [39]: %timeit matrix[0] = row
10 loops, best of 3: 68.7 ms per loop
```

Finally, the real meat of the solution is to avoid the LIL format whenever possible. While it's the most flexible format, it's also the slowest (generally). For instance, if you're just trying to build your matrix one row at a time, you can use [`scipy.sparse.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.vstack.html):

```
In [40]: %%timeit
   ....: for i in xrange(matrix.shape[0]):
   ....:   matrix[i] = row
   ....:
1 loops, best of 3: 3.14 s per loop

In [41]: %timeit ss.vstack([row for i in xrange(matrix.shape[0])])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop

In [44]: m2 = ss.vstack([row for i in xrange(matrix.shape[0])])

In [45]: numpy.allclose(matrix.todense(), m2.todense())
Out[45]: True
```

**EDIT**: If memory is a concern and you still want maximum speed, you can make your own `vstack` based on the [fast `vstack` for CSR matrices](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/construct.py#L396). I would start by copying the `_compressed_sparse_stack` function and calling it with your list of CSR rows and `axis = 0`. Then, you should be able to modify it to take an iterator instead of a list, which would avoid the high memory overhead. Or, you could inline the steps into your for loop. Either way, you'll lose a little speed, but potentially save a lot of memory.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This has indeed sped up the performance significantly, unfortunately I have run into memory problems doing so. By using vstack, not even 40 GB of memory successfully fits the entire process. You wouldn't happen to have any further ideas about this do you?

Comment: See my edit above. I haven't tried what I suggested, but I think it should work.